# select a value where it doesn't exist in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I have two tables

Table A:

```
ID
1
2
3
4
```

Table B:

```
ID
1
2
3
```

I have two requests:

- I want to select all rows in table A that table B doesn't have, which in this case is row 4.
- I want to delete all rows that table B doesn't have.

I am using SQL Server 2000.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

You could use `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT A.* FROM A WHERE ID NOT IN(SELECT ID FROM B)
```

However, meanwhile i prefer `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT A.* FROM A WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM B WHERE B.ID=A.ID)
```

There are other options as well, this article explains all advantages and disadvantages very well:

[Should I use NOT IN, OUTER APPLY, LEFT OUTER JOIN, EXCEPT, or NOT EXISTS?](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join)

Comment: how do you add another "where" statement in that? if you wanna say ````SELECT A.* FROM A WHERE A.ID=1 AND NOT EXISTS(...)````

Comment: @Chemist That's how you do it. Multiple where clauses can be combined with AND or OR, depending on the logic you require, with exactly the syntax you've used.

Answer (score 42):

For your first question there are at least three common methods to choose from:

- NOT EXISTS
- NOT IN
- LEFT JOIN

The SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT NULL
    FROM TableB
    WHERE TableB.ID = TableA.ID
)

SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE ID NOT IN (
    SELECT ID FROM TableB
)

SELECT TableA.* FROM TableA 
LEFT JOIN TableB
ON TableA.ID = TableB.ID
WHERE TableB.ID IS NULL
```

Depending on which database you are using, the performance of each can vary. For [SQL Server](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/) (not nullable columns):

> NOT EXISTS and NOT IN  predicates are the best way to search for missing values, as long as both columns in question are NOT NULL.

Answer (score 3):

```
select ID from A where ID not in (select ID from B);
```

or

```
select ID from A except select ID from B;
```

Your second question:

```
delete from A where ID not in (select ID from B);
```

Comment: Except is not in SQL Server 2000.

Answer (score 3):

This would select 4 in your case

```
SELECT ID FROM TableA WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM TableB)
```

This would delete them

```
DELETE FROM TableA WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM TableB)
```

Comment: EXCEPT is not part of SQL Server 2000.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT ID 
  FROM A 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1
                     FROM B
                    WHERE B.ID = A.ID
                 )
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT ID
  FROM A
 WHERE ID NOT IN (
      SELECT ID
        FROM B);
```

---

```
SELECT ID    
  FROM A a
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 
        FROM B b
       WHERE b.ID = a.ID)
```

---

```
         SELECT a.ID 
           FROM A a    
LEFT OUTER JOIN B b 
             ON a.ID = b.ID    
          WHERE b.ID IS NULL
```

---

```
DELETE 
  FROM A 
 WHERE ID NOT IN (
      SELECT ID 
        FROM B)
```

Comment: Is this syntax valid? Shouldn't it be where ID not in (...)?

Comment: This will not work. Correct syntax should be: `SELECT ID FROM A WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM B);`